# FactoryGirl with Rspec in Rails Unknown Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

So I am dealing  with Rspec testing and FactoryGirl. I'm still a bit confused as to the inner workings of FactoryGirl when an object is created or built.

I have a few test results that look similar to this:

```
 Failure/Error: @ticket = FactoryGirl.create(:ticket)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user=' for #<Ticket:0x007f1455e72fc8>
 # ./spec/models/ticket_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It seems as if it is trying to assign an instance of ticket to user but why? And where would I start to try to fix it?

**Update**

I am just getting familiar with this code base and so I just realized there is no ticket factory or user factory. Is this way of creating a ticket for testing incorrect? Sorry for ignorance, I'm still very green with FactoryGirl and test frameworks in general.

Comment: Please post your `ticket` and `user` factories including `ticket_spec.rb`

Comment: I'm just asking for a suggestion as to where to go. I can't post work code mate.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please let me know why.

Comment: in that case you should get started with the [`Getting Started`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your factories, most likely in `spec/factories.rb` or in a `spec/factories` folder. More info: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

```rb
 # spec/factories.rb

 factory :user do
   # assuming this passes model validations
 end

 factory :ticket do
   # assuming this passes model validations
   user
 end
```

Comment: Thank you I just found the factories in that file. I Realized the problem is that though there is a User class, the Ticket instance calls it 'owner' instead. i.e. belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'. Is there a way to define that in the factory?

Comment: I believe you can define it like this `factory :owner, class: User`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't try with your method because there was already an alias for owner in the user factory. ie. factory :user, aliases: [:owner]. But changing 'user' to 'owner' worked thanks for your help!